# why expect command works where stdin redirection fails?

Tags: bash, stdin, expect

I've seen that for some programs, the only way to pass text to their prompt is to use the `expect` command.

Redirecting input from file or using a "here document" does not work. **What does expect do pass correctly the text?**

Comment: What do you mean "does not work" ? `expect` is perfectly capable of handling heredocs and redirected input. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code

Comment: @Aserre, consider `ssh` where you cannot write `echo "password" | ssh user@remote`, but you must actually type the password when ssh asks for it. (disregarding for now that there are better and more secure ways to do ssh authentication)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, for security reasons, when `ssh` needs to read the user's password it does not read from `stdin` which can be a *tty*, *file*, *pipe*, or *fifo*. Instead, `ssh` directly opens `/dev/tty` and reads the password from it which is guaranteed to be a *tty* if it exists (otherwise `ssh` would fail if `/dev/tty` is not available).

See following example (on Linux):

```
$ strace ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password 127.0.0.1
[...]
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)                = 4
close(4)                                = 0
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)                = 4
[...]
write(4, "root@127.0.0.1's password: ", 27) = 27
root@127.0.0.1's password:
read(4,
```

What Expect does is create a [pty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) and run commands on that pty.